# .SQL export from PHPMyAdmin to Excel or CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv, dump

I inherited some old records for a company I volunteer for.  One of the old files is an SQL Dump from their old webpage, and I would like to get the data from one of the tables for their use into Excel.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
```

The dump drops the table if it exists, creates the table new, and then inserts all of the data.

Is there some easy way I can get this data into Excel on my PC?  I don't have SQL Server or anything like that loaded... I assumed there was some easy way to get a CSV or Excel file out of it but I have failed to find this yet without first uploading the dump to some SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think that there is any way to export a dump file into an excel or .CSV file. The reason for this is that the dump file is actually a collection of Select statements instead of the actual data itself. SQL servers do this to prevent a whole list of problems that can occur when you try to manipulate raw data manually.

Lucky for you, MySQL offers a free version of their server. You can find it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

I think you are best off downloading this and restoring your file as a new database. This has the added benefit of allowing you complete control over the data from that point on. Exporting to excel would be easy at that point however, you may find it a lot more fulfilling to continue using MySQL server.

Hope this helped.